# How to parse http response as a string?

Tags: javascript

I am new in Java and JavaScript and I was looking for a way to take an HTTPResponse, parse the `.responseText` using the `.indexOf` method so as to take the property I need and after that display this value in a cell of a table row I have created in an html page. Is there a way to replace this cell every time I get the `httpresponse`?

Thanks a lot.

```
var xHRObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://meteovarkiza.gr/";
xHRObject.open("GET", url, true);
xHRObject.send();
xHRObject.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xHRObject.readyState==4 && xHRObject.status==200) {
    var response = xHRObject.responseText;
    var startIndex = response.indexOf("Temperature");
    startIndex += 70;
    var subResponse = response.slice(startIndex, startIndex + 4);                
            alert(subResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Is there a way?"* - yes

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: It has nothing to do with java, I was just making it clear. I have tried creating an object that takes this value but after that, I can't display it in the html table.

Comment: Code goes in the question. It's really hard to read it in a comment since it's all squished together.

Comment: One question before we can continue. Is `http://meteovarkiza.gr/` your website and is that code running on one of the pages of that site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I have tried creating an object that takes this value but after that, I can't display it in the html table."*

Your question isn't very clear, but you seem to be saying that you are successfully getting the particular value you need out of the response text and into the `subResponse` variable, but you don't know how to put that value into a particular element on your page.

If so, the simplest way is to give that element an `id`:

```
<td id="resultCell"></td>
```

And then do this in your JS:

```
document.getElementById("resultCell").innerHTML = subResponse;
```

In your question title you said:

> *"How to parse http response as a string?"*

...but you seem to have figured that out. If you have no control over the response format then I guess a combination of regex tricks and/or `.indexOf()` and `.slice()` (or [`.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) might be better since in your case you always specify 4 characters) is the way to do it.

If you can set the format of the response you are probably much better off returning a JSON string, because then you can use `JSON.parse()` to get an object with directly accessible properties - no more messing around with string manipulation.

Comment: Thanks a lot nnnnnn. Yes this was exactly what I meant.!!!

Just one step further: How can I trigger the request periodically i.e every 2 minutes?

Comment: Put your code in a function, for the sake of an example let's say `function refreshTemperature()`, and then you can say `setInterval(refreshTemperature,120000)` to automatically call the function every 120000 milliseconds. Or use `setTimeout(refreshTemperature,120000)` from the end of the function so that each time it runs it schedules another call to itself. Note that in the `setInterval()` call `refreshTemperature` does not have `()` after it. MDN has more [info about `setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) and `setTimeout()`.